# Tablas flotantes en el modelo de base de datos?

Tags: mysql

Se supone que si nosotros vamos a usar un gestor relacional de base de datos como por ejemplos mysql debemos tener todas las tablas relacionadas? o se puede dar el caso que tengamos tablas flotantes de que dependería eso?

Comment: A qué llamas una "tabla flotante" ?

Comment: @leonbloy creo que se refiere a una tabla que no tiene ninguna relación con otra tabla del tipo _uno a uno_, _uno a muchos_, etc.

Comment: si a eso mismo me refiero,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si no entiendo mal, por "tablas relacionadas" entiendes aquellas tablas que referencian a (o son referenciadas por) otras tablas, normalmente mediante "claves foráneas".  Por supuesto, esto es lo habitual en un diseño de base de datos relacional. Pero es perfectamente válido (y no raro) tener tablas "no relacionadas" (lo que tú llamas tablas flotantes).

Por otro lado: es un error de concepto (o de terminología) muy común, el de creer que la palabra "**relación**" (cuando uno habla de **bases de datos relacionales**) alude a estas "relaciones entre tablas". No es así; en el [modelo relacional](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo_relacional), la "relación" es lo que comunmente llamamos "tabla".
En inglés diferencian (aunque ellos también se [confunden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27268711/what-is-the-difference-between-an-entity-relationship-model-and-a-relational-mod)) "relation" y "relationship",  lamentablemente nosotros usamos el término "relación" para ambas cosas.

Comment: Interesante! Cuando hablamos entonces del concepto (por ejemplo) _uno a muchos_, ¿el termino correcto sería relaciones o referencias?

Comment: @OscarR. No está mal usar "relación" también para "relationship" (como usamos al hablar de "diagramas entidad-relación"), lo que hay que evitar es confundir esto con "el modelo relacional de base de datos". La palabra  "referencia" yo la usaría solo para la relacion "física" (es decir, a dónde apunta una clave foránea), el concepto de "relacion" (relationship) es más abstracto (por ejemplo, una relacion muchos-a-muchos suele involucar una tabla intermedia y un par de "referencias").

Comment: Claro y conciso, enhorabuena!